# How to transfer rigged model from Blender to Maya?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, import, file-format

What is the best way to export a rigged model from Blender to Maya?

Which format is preferable, should some settings be tweaked? Or is the whole idea wrong and the rig won't work properly after importing to Maya?

Comment: Maya's rigging system is completely different. You may transfer bones and weights, but that's about it. Constraints, drivers and scripted functionality is without guarantee with most things needed to be redone.

Comment: @Jerryno Thank you for the response! At least bones and weights should work fine, or it's  also not for sure?