# How to properly transfer Blender animation to Maya?

Tags: animation, export, external-applications, .fbx, alembic

I found this [Curiosity rover](https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/curiosity-dirty) from NASA, which is actually animated and is in blender format. I want to use this rover in my personal student showreel. That's the reason I want it to export, along with textures and animation to Maya for lighting and render passes kind of stuff.

I tried doing export, in FBX, but in Maya when I opened it. The result outputs something like this:

[image: nasty export]

Is there any step I'm missing? Am I not exporting the animation properly?

I tried researching on the internet about this, but the only thing I found was opposite of it (Maya to Blender). The nearest question I found is [How to transfer rigged model from Blender to Maya?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/87065/22125). Even if it is about rigging, it says rigs can't be exported to Maya. In that case, can I bake the animation and export?

I have found [similar post](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/40vkqh/help_exporting_animation_from_blender_to_maya/) on Reddit. But it's unclear how to do it. FBX file exported from blender doesn't show up in MAX's import dialog.

#### EDIT 1:

If everything fails, can I export stationary model (with texture) to Maya?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87065/how-to-transfer-rigged-model-from-blender-to-maya

Comment: How about baking animation and then sending? Or just transfer model with textures and no animation?

Comment: There is a  "Search Q&A" box at the top right of the page, please start there. https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=baking+animation or https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=texture+fbx